# How to make a function to return value in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, parameter-passing

I am new to Entity Framework.
Previously i was working with Sql. I was using this code

```
 public string Get_Value(string tablename,string retreiveCol,string Condition)
    {
    string MyValue = "";
    DataSet ds = GetData("select "+retreiveCol+"from "+tablename+" where "+Condition);
        if (ds != null)
        {
            MyValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
        return MyValue;
    }

    public static DataSet GetData(string sql)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionSettings.DBConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        sql = sql.Replace("\r\n", " ");
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            return null;
        return ds;
    }
```

I was calling this method in this way

```
String myval=Get_Value("tablename","retreiveCol","Condition");
```

please help me to create a method where i can pass fieldname and can get a value using entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not that simple in EF as EF is ORM and during programming we deal with UnitOfWork classes (represented by classes deriving from DbContext) and entities classes (each of them is representation of given table). I would suggest to use following method:

```
object Get_Value<EntityType>(string fieldName, Expression<EntityType,bool> condition)
{
     using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
     {
         object entity = context.Set<EntityType>().SingleOrDefault(condition);
         return entity.GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(entity);
     } 
}
```

Then you might use it like it (for exemplary Album table represented by Album class):

```
object value = Get_Value<Album>("Name", album => album.Price > 100.0);
```

You might even better prepare Get_Value as an extension method for you DbContext class.